# Trading service uploads to Draft status possible using Ebay SDK using davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php

Tags: php, sdk, ebay-api

I like to upload a lot of items at once but I'd like them to be saved in draft for final review. Is this possible through the trading service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no operation in the API that allows listings to be saved as a draft.